# Elements in the project file, what do they do?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I did some copy and replace in my Razor component project, and now I can see these in the project file. What do they actually do? By the way, the SignOut page cannot be found at runtime.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Pages\SignOut.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Remove="Pages\SignOut.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Pages\SignOut.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Pages\SignOut.razor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Just delete them.

Comment: `What do they actually do?` A lot of damage to your self-confidence... Just get rid of them terrorists, and your app will work properly.

Comment: I go with Enet on this one. They are ghosts left behind by various copy/paste type activities.  Visual Studio is still bad at handling copy/past operations on Razor Components and can get itself in a real mess.  @Enet - why not post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What it actually does is configuring how your source files will be handled during build.

In this case the `SignOut.razor` is removed from the list of `Content` files (to be included as content in the build) (and a some other lists), and added to the `None`-list (ignore these files during build). Some of these can be configured in VS in the file properties pane under `Build action`.

For a razor file to be compiled and working in a blazor app, it needs to have the build action `Content`, and be in the content-files list.

Content is the default action for razor files, which is why (as previously commented) those lines in the project file can be removed. Why they got there in they first place is (also as previously commented) due to VS not really keeping up with the file operations.

Comment: "vs not keeping up with the file operations" I added a second razor page to a tiny Blazor app and this happened. It's embarrassing!

Comment: This is insane! Why is this the only mention of "UpToDateCheckInput" "_ContentIncludedByDefault" on the entire internet? Why is this still happening 2 years later?